# Why is z-index not working with CSS columns in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, z-index, css-multicolumn-layout

I am having a problem with the `z-index` of my multi-column layout created with `column-count`. I want to move the clicked div on top of the list with `.animate()`, but when I am clicking an element on the right column it goes behind the elements of the left column. This works fine on Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome.

Any ideas?

```js
function gotoTop(element) {
    var destinationTop = $('.categories').offset().top;
    var elementOffsetTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var distanceTop = (elementOffsetTop - destinationTop);
    return distanceTop;
}

function gotoLeft(element) {
    var destinationLeft = $('.categories').offset().left;
    var elementOffsetLeft = $(element).offset().left;
    var distanceLeft = (elementOffsetLeft - destinationLeft);
    return distanceLeft;
}
$('.category').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('position', 'relative');
    $(this).css('z-index', '9999');
    $(this).siblings().css('z-index', '10');
    $(this).animate({
            top: '-' + gotoTop(this) + 'px',
            left: '-' + gotoLeft(this) + 'px'
        }, 2000
    );
});
```

```css
.categories {
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 7px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 7px;
    column-gap: 0px;
    background: grey;
}

.category {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 26px;
    border-left: 1px groove black;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    border-bottom: 2px groove #666;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="categories">
    <ul class="category" id="1">
        <li>Div 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="2">
        <li>Div 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="3">
        <li>Div 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="4">
        <li>Div 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="5">
        <li>Div 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="6">
        <li>Div 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="7">
        <li>Div 7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="8">
        <li>Div 8</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="9">
        <li>Div 9</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="10">
        <li>Div 10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="11">
        <li>Div 11</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="12">
        <li>Div 12</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="13">
        <li>Div 13</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="14">
        <li>Div 14</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="15">
        <li>Div 15</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="16">
        <li>Div 16</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="17">
        <li>Div 17</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="18">
        <li>Div 18</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsotir/s2AfU/3/)

Comment: I have updated your css. And problem is solved. See my answer

Answer (score 5):

Use `transform: translateZ` instead of `z-index`.

```
$(this).css('transform','translateZ(1px)');
$(this).siblings().css('transform','translateZ(0px)');
```

This will stack the elements correctly so that the element you clicked on is on top.

I've updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s2AfU/4/

Comment: this is a Good one ;)

Comment: This is a brilliant workaround, but I can't seem to get it to work in IE(11). Any ideas?

Comment: In my case (can't show the markup sadly) but basically a list (`<ul>`) was wrapped in 5 columns with a gap.  And I applied a hint.css tooltip that was "cut" - after trying some tricks, `transform: scale3d(1,1,1)` works best for a good result in chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like Chrome creates a separate layer for each column, and you can't control its `z-index`. I'd suggest the solution with [CSS3 Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead CSS3 Columns:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/r5q12u40/2/)

```js
function gotoTop(element) {
    var destinationTop = $('.categories').offset().top;
    var elementOffsetTop = $(element).offset().top;
    var distanceTop = (elementOffsetTop - destinationTop);
    return distanceTop;
}

function gotoLeft(element) {
    var destinationLeft = $('.categories').offset().left;
    var elementOffsetLeft = $(element).offset().left;
    var distanceLeft = (elementOffsetLeft - destinationLeft);
    return distanceLeft;
}

$('.category').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('position', 'relative');
    $(this).css('z-index', '9999');
    $(this).siblings().css('z-index', '10');
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-' + gotoTop(this) + 'px',
        left: '-' + gotoLeft(this) + 'px'
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.categories {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    background: grey;
}

.category {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    min-height: 26px;
    border-left: 1px groove black;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    border-bottom: 2px groove #666;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="categories">
    <ul class="category" id="1">
        <li>Div 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="2">
        <li>Div 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="3">
        <li>Div 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="4">
        <li>Div 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="5">
        <li>Div 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="6">
        <li>Div 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="7">
        <li>Div 7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="8">
        <li>Div 8</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="9">
        <li>Div 9</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="10">
        <li>Div 10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="11">
        <li>Div 11</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="12">
        <li>Div 12</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="13">
        <li>Div 13</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="14">
        <li>Div 14</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="15">
        <li>Div 15</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="16">
        <li>Div 16</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="17">
        <li>Div 17</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category" id="18">
        <li>Div 18</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible at all. Because as you see the element on the right side are getting behind the whole left column.

I don't know how exactly `column-count` works in DOM, but I think it creates two parts (your two column), and all these `<ul>`s are children of that columns, and these column cannot overlap each other. And with `z-index` if an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B. I think this is a case here.

here I create a [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sR5jblXfFXOUA7klYNqn?p=preview) so you can see better

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your Fiddle. You didn't need to use `column-gap` and `column-count`. just use `float` property of css. 
Watch this fiddle no javascript change. Just a css change. I hope this will solve your problem(Working on all browsers)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/s2AfU/5/)

Comment: How about sorting? You changed it with your CSS.

Comment: Did you specifically want that order? I mean are the div sections has something  to do with numbering

Comment: I don't know. You said "You didn't need to use `column-gap` and `column-count`", but sorting in your code is not equivalent to the sorting in the question's code.